# How to write nested for loops in efficient way in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on a scenario where I need to have nested for loops. I am able to get the desired output though but thought there might be some better way to achieve that too.

I am having the sample DF and wanted the output in the below format

```
List(/id=1/state=CA/, /id=2/state=MA/, /id=3/state=CT/)
```

Below snippet does the job but any suggestion improve it.

Example:

```
val stateDF = Seq(
 (1, "CA"),
 (2, "MA"),
 (3, "CT")
).toDF("id", "state")

 var cond = ""
 val columnsLst =List("id","state")
 var pathList = List.empty[String]

for (row <- stateDF.collect) {
   cond ="/"
   val dataRow = row.mkString(",").split(",")
   for (colPosition <- columnsLst.indices) {
      cond = cond + columnsLst(colPosition) + "=" + dataRow(colPosition) + "/"
   }
   pathList = pathList ::: List(cond)
}
println(pathList)
```

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Never append to `List`. 2) Don't `collect` first and do all the work later. Do the heavy work first, collect later. 3) Look up the methods `zip` and `map`. 4) Maybe post on Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: To expand a little on the above. When you collect you pull everything back to the driver. This will hurt with large Dataframes because you will be doing work in your driver rather than the executors on your cluster. Also do your very best to eliminate mutable state (use val rather than var). If you have to accumulate something (in this case cond) then consider fold/foldLeft or a tail recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `dataframe` to the format you want, and do a `collect` later if needed, here is the sample code:

```
scala> stateDF.select(concat(lit("/id="), col("id"),lit("/state="),  col("state"), lit("/")).as("value")).show
+---------------+
|          value|
+---------------+
|/id=1/state=CA/|
|/id=2/state=MA/|
|/id=3/state=CT/|
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the sugestion. Now I come up the below for my above requirement.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame}
val stateDF = Seq(
(1, "CA"),
(2, "MA"),
(3, "CT")
).toDF("id", "state")

val allStates = stateDF.columns.foldLeft(stateDF) {
  (acc: DataFrame, colName: String) =>
    acc.withColumn(colName, concat(lit("/" + colName + "="), col(colName)))
}
val dfResults = allStates.select(concat(allStates.columns.map(cols => col(cols)): _*))
val columnList: List[String] = dfResults.map(col => col.getString(0) + "/").collect.toList
println(columnList)
```